# jQuery tooltip in a dynamicaly loaded div content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function for tooltip (works fine):

```
$('.tooltip').jBox('Tooltip', {
   closeOnMouseleave: true,
   ajax: {
      url: 'tooltips/tooltip.jsp',
      reload: true,
      getData: 'data-ajax',
      setContent: true,
      spinner: true
   }
});
```

and then I have this function for loading a div content every ten seconds (works fine):

```
$('#responsecontainer').load('live.jsp');
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $('#responsecontainer').load('live.jsp');
      }, 30000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
} );
```

This links works fine everywhere, except in dynamically loaded div.

```
<a class="tooltip" data-ajax="id=5" href="tooltip.html"Link</a>
```

Does anyone know how to make this link work when it is in the contetnt of the dynamically loaded div? Thank you very much

Comment: The tooltip plugin most likely has an update method, exactly for this reason.  Alternatively, just call the whole tooltip setup again, after you add new elements.

Comment: Looks to me like you've just missed a closing `>`. `<a class="tooltip" data-ajax="id=5" href="tooltip.html">Link</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jBox comes with an attach() method: https://stephanwagner.me/jBox/methods#attaching-jbox

You should use this method to attach your jBox and place your jBox in an variable:

```
var myJBox = new jBox('Tooltip', {
   closeOnMouseleave: true,
   attach: '.tooltip',
   ajax: {
      url: 'tooltips/tooltip.jsp',
      reload: true,
      getData: 'data-ajax',
      setContent: true,
      spinner: true
   }
});
```

Then you can reattach the jBox anytime with `myJBox.attach()`:

```
$('#responsecontainer').load('live.jsp', function () { myJBox.attach(); });
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $('#responsecontainer').load('live.jsp', function () { myJBox.attach(); });
   }, 30000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
} );
```

This way you make sure that jBox won't attach itself to an element multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reapply the tooltip as the DOM content is changed.
Create a function

```
function applyTooltip () {
$('.tooltip').jBox('Tooltip', {
   closeOnMouseleave: true,
   ajax: {
      url: 'tooltips/tooltip.jsp',
      reload: true,
      getData: 'data-ajax',
      setContent: true,
      spinner: true
   }
});

}
```

call the function on JQuery load callback

```
$('#responsecontainer').load('live.jsp', applyTooltip);
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $('#responsecontainer').load('live.jsp', applyTooltip);
      }, 30000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
} );
```

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: While this works, it's not the best practice. Check out my answer, it's better to use the .attach() method to make sure you won't attach jBox multiple times.

Comment: Agreed with @StephanWagner, best practice would be to use attach() method. Though I still wonder when the element is already removed from the DOM along with its bindings how the jBox is attached multiple times? Help me understand it if I missed something.